# Represent a vector with a scalar value

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

I have a system that returns vector representation of my input, but instead of a vector, I want to get a single number. Hence, my question is, is there any method that converts(represents, encodes) a vector to a single scalar value?

Using the norm of the vector might be a solution, but since I am not good at linear algebra(or maths in general), I thought it may be a good idea to ask at here...

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by a single number? Magnitude of the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on the context.

There is no general way to encode a vector (which I assume to have more than one component, otherwise there is no problem) faithfully into a single value ie. in such a way that you can recover the original vector from this value. Intuitively the components correspond to degrees of freedom, so restricting from say 3 degrees of freedom to 1 degree of freedom is a irreversible loss of information/freedom.

Of cause there are instances, where a vector **is** uniquely determined by a single value:

- Let’s say you only consider vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ and you know that all the vectors you are interested in, have length/magnitude/norm 1, then any such vector corresponds uniquely to its angle with the $x$-axis. Note that our assumption that the vectors have length 1 is a restriction making us loose a degree of freedom, so it is not surprising that only one degree of freedom remains...
- If you are in a discrete setup, by which I mean vectors in $\Bbb N^k$, $\Bbb Z^k$ or $\Bbb F_p^k$ (strictly speaking only the last one has vectors, but ignore that for now), then you might have a chance to enumerate all vectors. In this case any vector corresponds to a unique number, but the usual operations on vectors (like addition, multiplication by a scalar etc.) will become weird, when trying to write them down with respect to that enumeration.

Of cause these examples are somewhat artificial and I doubt they are what you are after.

So there is one last option, what *representing a vector of a scalar* may be. Assuming the vector represents some kind of data, say a color, then you might be interested in some sort of information you can derive from the components of the vector, say brightness. The *euclidean norm* is just one of many useful values you can associate to a vector. Others may be the maximum of all components, the mean of the components, the variance of the components etc. etc. Which kind of value you use depends on the context of your data. But again, most of these values will not be faithful, in that you won’t be able to recover the vector, once you calculated the associated scalar.